# How to send data from one browser to another

Tags: javascript, html

Okey so I am trying to make a "task board/to do list" website where I can add and complete the tasks and they will show up on the separate screen. So what do I need to use to be able to send data to the website on the separate screen from my phone?

Sorry if I'm not clear with what I am asking.
I know HTML and usually program in JavaScript and that is what I hope I can use for this.

Tl:dr send from website on phone to website on another screen.

Comment: You need a server that creates/retrieves/updates/deletes your tasks. Your client (browser or app) needs to continously fetch any changes to the board either by a setInterval request or to use sockets so that your server can directly send any modifications to all your clients that are connected.

Comment: Also closing as too broad.

Comment: Yeah sorry for being to broad. What my goal is is to make this https://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-Wall-Mounted-Calender-and-Notificatio/. But I want to add a to do list that I can access through my phone. Thanks for the answer, I am really new to server stuff so I will have to try an decrypt what you said when I have learned more about it.

Comment: Yes, you need a webserver that stores your "tasks" in a database (simple sqllite will do imo) or in memory. Do you have any experience with servers (ex: php/nodejs?)

Comment: No I have no experience at all with PHP. And I have looked a little bit on nodejs.